# How to change TeX Live installer temp?

Tags: installing, texlive

I want to install TeX Live on NAS; the problem is that its built-in Linux has very small `/tmp` partition which is quickly filled by packages downloaded by installer. Yet I have a plenty of place on other partitions, so it would be nice to somehow change temp location it uses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it tries the $TMPDIR, $TMP and $TEMP environment settings before falling back to `/tmp`, so defining one of those in the environment should do the trick.